# After heartbleed, how can you safely distribute new certs?

Tags: certificates, heartbleed

It's been a while since I studied key distribution, so I may have some fundamental misunderstanding..

From what I remember, man in the middle attacks can't occur during cert distribution because the cert being distributed is protected by a higher level cert's key. The root keys are distributed on cd with the OS making them very unlikely to be forged. But with heartbleed, isn't it possible that even the root level private keys were compromised? How can you safely distribute new keys electronically under these circumstances?

Comment: Wouldn't it be "possible that even the root level private keys were compromised" even without heartbleed? $\;$

Comment: I guess my question is, are the root private keys ever in memory such that they could be compromised by something like heartbleed? And if so, how can you do mass cert redistribution with any reasonable expectation of security?

Comment: everything should be in memory , in some point of time !

Comment: I do not expect that root certificates are actually used for TLS sessions. They are probably just used for signing other certificates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normal, serious root CA are offline. They are hosted on machines which are *never* connected to any kind of network. This tends to make them immune to remote attacks, and that's the point.

---

Technically, the reasons which have warranted key renewal ("the bug was there, so there *might* have been a compromise that we don't know of") are still valid: it would be preposterous to claim that we found and removed the Last Bug Ever in OpenSSL, or, for that matter, in Apache (OpenSSL is a library, it is loaded in the address space of the Apache server, so any similar bug in Apache itself would be equally devastating). So there must be some remaining bugs, and your new key is as "potentially compromised" as the previous one. So don't sweat it...

Or said otherwise: the whole heartbleed panic is based on a suspicion of possible breach, which logically still applies, and has always applied since the first days of networks. The "heartbleed" bug is nothing qualitatively new; bugs with that level of seriousness are found several times per year in any significant piece of software. We can conclude that "we cannot be sure of anything" and that would be mathematically true, but impractical. If we want to cling to the idea that computers and networks are still usable, then we must accept that bugs exists, some of them being *vulnerabilities*, and that usual strategies (applying security fixes as soon as vendors publish them) is a valid strategy which will allow our servers to remain unscathed most of the time.

As a colleague of mine told me yesterday: fish group into swarms (technically called [shoals and schools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoaling_and_schooling)) to protect themselves from predators. When a dolphin grabs a fish, that specific fish probably thinks "why me ?" and has a feeling of injustice; but the shoaling strategy is still effective *on average*.

To a large extent, that's what we do with the mechanism of vulnerability publication and security patches. A vulnerability may be found because it has been observed to be used by a predator, and that's too bad for the victim, but at least the rest of the swarm benefits for the experience. We would really like to be more proactive and develop code with no bug, but alas Science has not come up with a way to reliably avoid bugs in software (though languages with strong typing and systematic array bound checks can help a lot).

Comment: Good response. I wonder if my question is still applicable to the cert's that are one level down from root. The Verisign's of the world may have their keys stored in a vault somewhere under mount doom, but even if you only have 1000 next level cert's, seems like you'd still have to fly each new key out in an armored suitcase.

Answer (score 1):

There are variety of ways to look into your question .

1. Apply the patch for the heartbleed bug and use openssl
2. Use Options to bypass heartbleed or versions of openssl that dont have heartbleed problem. more [here](http://heartbleed.com/)
3. Use some other Crypto Library (does not gaurentee it does not bleed later )

Basically, there is no fool proof way or ideal way to distribute keys or doing any crypto. the complexity of software would always be prone to errors of various degrees. we just need to keep testing, validating and be resilient to such changes

Comment: I don't see how your answer has anything to do with the question (which is really about the possibility of root CAs being compromised)

Comment: thats the reason why i have there different ways to look into the question, its not clear if the question is about heartbeat or distributing the keys